Participle clauses - the appropriate form of some participles
I have a question regarding the use of participle clauses.
I read quite a lot on the subject, but I still can't understand their use in some cases.
Here is the sentence from my CAE Student's Book:

Viewed through a telescope, the tall ship looked absolutely
magnificent.

What if I change the past participle passive "viewed" into its continuous form "being viewed" to emphasize that the two actions happened at the same time?

Being viewed through a telescope, the tall ship looked absolutely
magnificent.

I know that I can use continuous passive participle to mean an ongoing action. However, my teacher, who is British, said to me that this sentence isn't correct. Unfortunately, he couldn't explain why.
Could you tell me please what is the problem with this sentence?
My other question concerns the use of the participle in the following sentence:

Having found that he had run out of money, Peter realised there was no
point in staying in town any longer.

According to my English Grammar (English Grammar in Use, Murphy, 2019), when one action happens before something else, we use having (done) for the first action. But we can also say "after -ing". So I tried to apply this rule to the above sentence:

After finding that he had run out of money, Peter realised there was no
point in staying in town any longer.

But my English teacher said that this is not correct either.
I'm completely at a loss.
Could you please explain to me why we can't say like that?

P E Dant, on ELL, has [abbreviated and adjusted]:

Compare:
Continuous passive participle clause:

Being beaten by (the) snow, he died.

Passive:

Beaten by (the) snow, he died.

Active:

The snow beat him, (and) he died. [There is more than a hint of causality; in the active variant, a 'therefore' could arguably be
inserted; EA]

Being + past participle is almost identical in meaning here to the past participle alone, and the ing-form being can be omitted.
Being beaten here is a continuous passive participle. Without being, we have just a passive participle. Their meanings are nearly identical, and being can be omitted, but including being (in
the first example) emphasizes that he died because the snow beat
him: it points more strongly to a causal relationship. It "tells a
story", in a way, of the beating as it progresses.

However, with

Viewed through a telescope, the tall ship looked absolutely magnificent.

there is synchronicity or perhaps a hint of conditionality ('When' or 'If' might be inserted) and the addition of 'Being' brings out an inappropriate emphasis: the sentence becomes clunky. Not ungrammatical, but unidiomatic.
..............................
The other examples given

Having found that he had run out of money, Peter realised there was no point in staying in town any longer.

and

After finding that he had run out of money, Peter realised there was no point in staying in town any longer.

are again not ungrammatical, but the two realisations Peter makes are so closely related (both temporally and deductively) that these two expressions sound too disjointed.

Finding that he had run out of money, Peter realised there was no point in staying in town any longer.

locates the two perceptions very closely in time and logical relationship.

Thank you for this lucid and rigorous explanation of a typically hazy piece of English usage.

Dear @Edwin Ashworth, thank you so much for your detailed explanation!
If I understand you are saying that, in the first sentence we don’t need to emphasise that the two actions happen at the same time, using “being viewed”. What is more, we’d better not do that. If we did it, there would be a confusion, because “being viewed” can be understood as “because of”, whereas in this sentence “viewed” has a hypothetical meaning. Given that there is no other means to emphasise that the two actions happen at the same time, in this sentence it can be understood only from the context.

As to the second sentence, I also understand what you mean @Edwin Ashworth and, indeed, your explanation sounds reasonable. The only thing is that the answer key to my Storybook says that the sentence with “Having found…” would be correct here. This is where the confusion comes. According to the book and to my British teacher, we can say “having found”, but at the same time we can’t say “After having…” Could perhaps you or anyone else explain to me please why it is like that?

@Edwin Ashworth, am I correct that in the first sentence there is no means to emphasise that the two actions happen at the same time, and it can only be understood from the context?

As I say, the two suggestions are  not ungrammatical, but the two realisations Peter makes are so closely related (both temporally and deductively) that the use of either of these two expressions sounds too disjointed. Who knows how examiners etc rate inferior stylistic choices? As I say, using the 'Finding ...'-clause sounds more natural and locates the discovery and the deduction close together (in time etc), as is appropriate. The optimal choice. ////

See 'He went into the room, opening the door using a skeleton key': is the time sequence... for an overview of the semantic thrust of participial adjuncts. And yes, as I said, synchronicity or perhaps conditionality is probably involved in the 1st sentence. 'It didn't look too impressive to the naked eye, but this was deceptive. Viewed through a telescope, the tall ship looked absolutely magnificent.' is an example where context forces the conditional association.

Dear @Edwin Ashworth, thank you for the link! That is exactly what I wanted!
